# How to make chat app with maintain the chat history in Mobile php+nodeJS+socketIO+AppGyver

Tags: node.js, mobile, socket.io, chat, history

I'm thinking to do Chat application in **AppGyver**. For now I have chat app on web with **NodeJS** and **SocketIO**, messages are store in **MySQL**. I was thinking how to keep on phone messages history like **whatsapp**.

- The first thing that came to mind is that i store messages in **SQLite** on phone. But now bothering me the following problem, how to refresh the changes that were made while the user was not online? Perhaps to make a new table in **MySQL** which would contain changes made while the user is offline.

*For keeping the changes involves information about the deleted conversations, deleted or added messages.*

- The second thing that came to mind is that all the data which get from the server, to keep as json files. However, it is difficult to carry out the changes that have made while the user was not online. At every refreshment need to open all files, then find the appropriate value and make the change.

Which of these methods would you choose, or you may have a better solution?

I wonder if someone has done something similar and whether there might be a better solutions than mine?

Best regards.

Comment: what about logging every change and in client you need to remember only ID of last change client is aware of? when client connect, he will ask for changes since {some_id} and apply them on local storage

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean to do so. I want to know what is better kept in the json files or SQLite on mobile device?

The changes what i must store for each conversation are the number of new messages and the date when the conversation updated (updateed param is used for sorting rooms)

Rooms are only one to one.

Comment: It's hard to say what is better, it depends on a programmer's preferences. But since it's messaging app, you may want search history by date, dime, fulltext search in old messages and that kind of stuff. Also, in most scenarios you just need last X messages. JSON is not good choice for this.

Comment: I only search conversations by username. And one field updated for sorting conversations, where store date and time when conversation is last time updated.

Comment: JSON is not a way for storing data. For transfer between server and client is suitable, but not for storing. I familiar with AppGiver (or mobile development) so I don't know what options there are, but SQLite seems to be a reasonable choice.